# Java Script: how to calculate an angle between smartphone and plane?

Tags: javascript, augmented-reality

I make a mobile application - user scans the plane with camera and then application shows information about the flight (for example destination). I have a problem with calculation. I try to calculate angle between user (smartphone) and plane.

I set my position (position of smartphone) and position of a plane and then I calculate the angle:

```
let angle = calcAngleBetweenToVectors({
        latitude: userCoords.latitude,
        longitude: userCoords.longitude,
        altitude: 0},
    {
        latitude: planeCoords.latitude,
        longitude: planeCoords.longitude,
        altitude: 4343
        })



function calcAngleBetweenToVectors(v1: {latitude: number, longitude: number, altitude: number}, v2: {latitude: number, longitude: number, altitude: number}){
    let ab = v1.latitude * v2.latitude + v1.longitude + v2.longitude + v1.longitude * v1altitude * v2altitude;
    let THE_ABSOLUTE_VALUE_a = Math.sqrt(v1.latitude * v1.latitude + v1.longitude * v1.longitude + v1altitude * v1altitude);
    let THE_ABSOLUTE_VALUE_b = Math.sqrt(v2.latitude * v2.latitude + v2.longitude * v2.longitude + v2altitude * v2altitude);

    const angle = Math.acos(ab / (THE_ABSOLUTE_VALUE_a * THE_ABSOLUTE_VALUE_b));
    return angle;
}
```

I also tried to calculate tangent, but I'm not sure if it works for 3d:

```
let angle2 = Math.tan(samplePlanes[0].altitudeInMeters / distanceInMeters);
```

Is it the right way to calculate this angle between smartphone and plane? If no - any suggestions how to do this correctly? And is it necessary to standardize units when I set position of smartphone and plane?

[Image shows what I want to get:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8EJN.png)

Comment: Depends which angle are you wanting, there are two: azimuth and elevation/inclination depression/declination

Comment: I added an image to the post. It shows what I try to get.